# Encoding entities with features of continuous values

Tags: machine-learning, rnn, machine-learning-model

Given a set of *entities*, I would like to predict the next in the sequence; for this purpose, I would like to use RNN. However, my first challenge is how to model the *entities*.

A possible input sequence can be:

```
EntityType_1 -> \
EntityType_2 -> \
EntityType_1 -> \
EntityType_3
```

Where each entity, given its type, has a unique set of continuous properties. For instance, the above sequence including features can be:

```
EntityType_1 (x=0.1, y=0.8) -> \
EntityType_2 (z=0.5) -> \
EntityType_1 (x=0.9, y=0.3) -> \
EntityType_3 (i= 0.2, j=0.7)
```

I have more than 10,000 entity types, where each has anywhere between 0 to 10s of features.

Any thoughts on related work on modeling/encoding such entities?

Comment: We can use a [indicator variable](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat462/node/161/) to give a hint to the model whether or not to use the given feature for computation. For instance, in `EntityType_2`, we don't have features `x` and `y`, so we can set their respective indicator variable values to 0.

Comment: I guess that will be most useful when you have a "limited" set of parameters. In my case, the set of parameters is so big, e.g., `8n` where `n` is the number of entity types (note that `n` is easily bigger than `10,000`).